# Remove borders in nested table

Tags: html, css

How does one prevent the inheriting of borders in a nested tabled?

I tried to a add a borderless class to the nested table, but the borders of the parent class are still inherited.

```css
.plain_tbl {
  border: none;
}

.plain_tbl tr td {
  border: none;
}

.tbl {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.tbl tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td align=center style="padding:50px">
      <table border=0 class="plain_tbl">
        <tr>
          <td>0--------------------100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align=center> ^ <br>50</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am looking for a solution which does not change the parent class, i.e. how to make the nested class overwrite the parent class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is

```
.tbl tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

which will add a border to every `<td>` also if it is a table inside a table you could fix it by using

```
.tbl > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```css
.plain_tbl {
    border: none;
}
.plain_tbl tr td {
  border: none;
}

.tbl {
    border:1px solid;
}
.tbl > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td align=center style="padding:50px">

    <table border=0 class="plain_tbl">
    <tr><td>0--------------------100</td></tr>
    <tr><td align=center> ^ <br>50</td></tr>
    </table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Update, another solution then previous using specificity**

In the comments you asked

> why does the nested class not overwrite the parent class?

The reason is [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and the order of your CSS rules. If you are not allowed to change the CSS order you can change the specificity. You need to be more specific then this

```
.tbl tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

To be more specific you can change like so

```
.tbl .plain_tbl tr td {
    border: none;
}
```

run the code snippet and see it work

```css
.plain_tbl {
    border: none;
}
.tbl .plain_tbl tr td {
  border: none;
}
.plain_tbl tr td {
  border: none;
}

.tbl {
    border:1px solid;
}
.tbl tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td align=center style="padding:50px">

    <table border=0 class="plain_tbl">
    <tr><td>0--------------------100</td></tr>
    <tr><td align=center> ^ <br>50</td></tr>
    </table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Third method, only changing the order of your css**
 because both rules actually have the same specificity you can also just place the rule `.plain_tbl tr td` after `.tbl tr td {` in your css file like so:

```css
.plain_tbl {
  border: none;
}

/*
move this to the bottom
.plain_tbl tr td {
  border: none;
}
*/

.tbl {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.tbl tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

/* see here */
.plain_tbl tr td {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td align=center style="padding:50px">

    <table border=0 class="plain_tbl">
    <tr><td>0--------------------100</td></tr>
    <tr><td align=center> ^ <br>50</td></tr>
    </table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why does the nested class not overwrite the parent class?

Comment: any way to do this without changing the parent class?

Comment: @user813801 see the updated answer, I hope that answers your question. Otherwise feel free to comment again

Comment: that "after" part answers

Answer (score 1):

your problem lies with the order of rules, since `.tbl td` is more general, it also applied to the inner element, and since its the last rule applied, it overrides the previous rule, which is the more specific rule
.
so simply rearrange your css and fix

```css
.tbl {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.tbl tr td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.plain_tbl {
  border: none;
}

.plain_tbl tr td {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td align=center style="padding:50px">
      <table border=0 class="plain_tbl">
        <tr>
          <td>0--------------------100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align=center> ^ <br>50</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can f.e. remove the `plain_tbl` class completely, and just apply the border to table cells that are in rows that are direct descendants of your main table:

```
.tbl,
.tbl > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: any way to do this without changing the parent class?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Nothing needs to change in the HTML. (And if you don’t want to make changes in the CSS - well then I don’t know what the point of the question would be?)

Comment: i am asking how to make the nested class overwrite the parent class

Comment: Well for that you either just need to change the order of those rules (because they both have the same _specificity_), or make the `plain_tbl` selectors more specific.